# Load props file in EMR Spark Application

Tags: apache-spark, emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to load custom properties in my spark application using :-

```
command-runner.jar,spark-submit,--deploy-mode,cluster,--properties-file,s3://spark-config-test/myprops.conf,--num-executors,5,--executor-cores,2,--class,com.amazon.Main,#{input.directoryPath}/SWALiveOrderModelSpark-1.0-super.jar
```

However, I am getting the following exception:-

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
>   properties file 's3://spark-config-test/myprops.conf''. at
>   org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkArgument(CommandBuilderUtils.java:241)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.loadPropertiesFile(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:284)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.getEffectiveConfig(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:233)
>   at org

Is this the correct way to load file from S3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't load a properties file directly from S3.  Instead you will need to download the properties file to your master node somewhere, then submit the spark job referencing the local path on that node.  You can do the download by using command-runner.jar to run the aws cli utility.

Comment: This is also the case for files like spark-default.conf and yarn-xml files as well?

Comment: No, Amazon provides a configuration API to set all the spark/hadoop specific settings.  Essentially you provide a JSON object with keys like "yarn.some.setting".  Details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html

Comment: I am using spark-defaults classification and providing the following property:- spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.FOO = "foo". Will this be visible in the executors as well?

Comment: No, that property only affects the master.