# Where to put application property file for spark application running on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am submitting one spark application job jar to EMR, and it is using some property file. So I can put it into S3 and while creating the EMR I can download it and copy it at some location in EMR box if this is the best way how I can do this while creating the EMR cluster itself at bootstrapping time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535424/load-props-file-in-emr-spark-application

Comment: It’s not duplicate of that I want to know how to do this while creating the Emr cluster itself

Comment: I personally store my applications on s3 and load them on bootstrap. But I'm not sure if this is the answer that you are looking for...

Comment: If you're running your job as an EMR step with `spark-submit`, you can reference the file directly in S3: `spark-submit .... --files s3://mybucket/my/config/file`

Answer (score 0):

Check following snapshot

[image]

In edit software setting you can add your own configuration or JSON file ( which stored on S3 location ) and using this setting you can passed configure parameter to EMR cluster on creating time. For more details please check following links

[Amazon EMR Cluster Configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-emr-cluster-configuration.html)

[Configuring Applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html)

[AWS ClI](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1502)

hope this will help you.